# Angular2/4 search suggestion

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I'm develop a drop down suggestion search box in angular 2/4. When typing on text box  and press search button the searched details are displayed.**But Here** i want to show the  searching, ‘as-you-type’ suggestion  want to displayed(Like a dropdown search)
.I saw so many techniques in different place but its not working. Here i install angular material I got some error in my node modules

**i want like this**
[image]

here I will try the pipe but its not working..Can any one please help me..

**my html is**

```html
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
               <div [innerHTML]="highlighted"></div>
             <input name="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"
                  (keyup)="FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)"
                  [(ngModel)]="searchcontent">                       
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-success ProductSearchBtn" type="button" 
                      (click)='FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)'>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span style="margin-left:10px;">Search</span>
                  </button>
               </span>
          </div>                  
    </div>
```

component.ts

```js
     FetchItemDetailsSearch(itemcodeordesc: string): void {

        {
            this.highlight= this.searchcontent
                ? itemcodeordesc.replace(new RegExp('(' + this.searchcontent + ')', 'ig'),
                    '<span class=highlight>$1</span>')
                : itemcodeordesc;
        }

        this.pageIndex = 1;
        this.searchflag = 1;

        if (itemcodeordesc.length > 0)
            this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
        else {
            itemcodeordesc = undefined
            this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
        }
        this.prevScrollPosition = 0;
        this._enqService.FetchItemDetailsSearch(this.searchcontent,this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
            error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
            });
    }
```

**Here i got like this(this is the problem, not showing the suggestion)**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code in stackblitz?

Comment: @Akhil Is it working if you click on the search button?

Comment: @Shantanu its working but  search box is not see any suggestions like the above picture

Comment: I asked just to use the same libraries you are using for ui . Anyway, I have given an example where  for ui, I have used angular material. Check :)

Comment: @Debojyoti when i use angular material i got error ?

Comment: @brock What is the error?

Comment: @Debojyoti      
Error  Build:Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.etc.... E:\Akhil\local\...node_modules\@angular\material\autocomplete\typings\autocomplete-origin.d.ts 15

Comment: Try the steps I have mentioned to install angular material. Your angular version is not latest. If you follow all the steps I have mentioned, all your packages will get updated to latest versions @brock

Comment: @Debojyoti  when i try to update my project i got like this
E:\demo\Project>ncu -u
No package.json

Please add a package.json to the current directory, specify the --packageFile or --packageData options, or pipe a package.json to stdin.

Comment: From where are you executing the command?
Run it from the root directory of your project @brock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176403/discussion-between-brock-and-debojyoti).

Answer (score 1):

For the dropdown implementation, you can use **[angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)**

Use the the [**autocomplete**](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component for ui

Demo template

> **HTML**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (keyup)="updated()" [(ngModel)]="data">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Now to search with in an array of string (In this example `all[]`),
you can use this **logic**

Here I am using regex to match any substring of  those strings in the array

> **Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = [];
  data : any;
  constructor() {
  }

  public updated() {
    this.options = [];
    if (this.myControl.value.length > 0) {
      let all = ['John', 'Jenny', 'Jonson']
      let searchedWord = this.myControl.value
      for(let key in all) {
        let r = all[key].search(new RegExp(searchedWord, "i"));
        if (r != -1) {
          this.options.push(all[key])
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.options = []
    }
  }
}
```

Working example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-material-search)

> Install angular material and animations

#### Step - 1 : **Delete** all node modules

Delete all the files from node modules folder

#### Step - 2 : **Update** all the packages to latest version

`npm i -g npm-check-updates`

`ncu -u`

`npm install`

#### Step - 3 : **Install** angular **material** and **animation**

`npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`

`npm install --save @angular/animations`

#### Step - 4 : Import any theme as it is required to use the libarary

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

#### Step - 4 : Modify app.modules.ts file

**Imports**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```

NgModule Meta data

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,MatFormFieldModule,MatAutocompleteModule,MatInputModule,ReactiveFormsModule,BrowserAnimationsModule ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have attached the links of angular material documentation in the answer, also try the live demo in my new edit :)

Comment: I explained the way to install angular material and animation without any version error @Akhil

Comment: better than make a loop, Use this.options=all.filter(p=>p.search(new RegExp(searchedWord, "i"))>=0) to filter the result

Comment: I didn't get you. Please explain briefly

Comment: how to change my ts file like your answer \

Answer (score 1):

[Material autocomplete example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-autocomplete-configuration)

intsall angular material:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

for Animation:

```
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

Include Theme in style.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // angular animation module


import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,MatFormFieldModule,MatAutocompleteModule,MatInputModule,ReactiveFormsModule,BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Filter Name" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface User {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    { name: 'Mary' },
    { name: 'Masy' },
    { name: 'Maty' },
    { name: 'Mvry' },
    { name: 'Mbry' },
    { name: 'Shelley' },
    { name: 'Igor' }
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith<string | User>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
      map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: when i got install the angular material i got error

Comment: please describe you error. and update you angular version as well.

Comment: st install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-text-input-autocomplete@0.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Akhil No description
npm WARN Akhil No repository field.
npm WARN Akhil No README data
npm WARN Akhil No license field.

+ @angular/material@6.3.3
+ @angular/cdk@6.3.3
updated 2 packages in 2.691s

Comment: install latest version of angular 6.0.7.

Comment: i also install the latest version

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli

and npm install  --save @angular/cli. check angular version in package.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174768/discussion-between-akhil-and-unluckyaj).

Answer (score 0):

Try using (input) instead of (keyup) in the input like this:

```
<input name="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"
          (input)="FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)"
          [(ngModel)]="searchcontent">
```

**Edit:**

Try replacing **this.searchcontent** with **itemcodeordesc** in the **FetchItemDetailsSearch** function like below:

```
this._enqService.FetchItemDetailsSearch(itemcodeordesc,this.pageIndex)
.subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
```

Comment: its not getting

Comment: Try adding an alert("here"); at the beginning of the FetchItemDetailsSearch function to check if the function is reachable at keystroke.

Comment: If the alert shows when typing then the function is called but there's an error preventing it to work properly only when called from the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Pipe** which will use   [(ngModel)]="searchcontent" over the mainList declared and defined in your component.ts file

mainList: any[] = [];

inside constructor ->  define which properties you want for search results

this.mainList= ['property1', 'property2',..,'propertyN'];

Use for loop to display the results in your page-

*ngFor="let x of xs| pipe: searchcontent: mainList"

Comment: you should implement PipeTransform for your purpose.

Comment: refer  https://angular.io/guide/pipes or https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c